# How to underline navbar item when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, for-loop

I have a navbar which underlines the menu item you hover with left -100 to 0% effect. I want to underline menu item when it is clicked. I can't understand why my for loop does not work as I would expect. I created "x" variable with the thought that it will increase by 1 at each loop iteration but this does not happen because when I click last item, the second element is selected.

```js
const menu_links = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-link");
const active = document.querySelectorAll(".link-mark");

for (let i = 0; i < menu_links.length; i += 1) {
  var x = 0;
  menu_links[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    const current = document.getElementsByClassName("link-active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("link-active", "");
    active[x].classList.add("link-active");
  })
  x += 1;
}
```

```css
.underline {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  left: -100%;
  background-color: #3399FF;
}

ul li a:hover>.underline {
  left: 0%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.link-active {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: #3399FF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      Main Page<div class="link-mark underline link-active"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      Blog<div class="link-mark underline"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      Contact<div class="link-mark underline"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      More<div class="link-mark underline"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why your `<div>` are empty ?

Comment: Because it's for :hover effect, look at css.

Comment: can not see that because `#navigation` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looking to do something like that ?

```js
const myMenu = document.getElementById('menu');

myMenu.onclick=e=>  // JS event delegation
  {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a' ) return; // only
  e.preventDefault;
  let LI = e.target.parentElement;

  if (!LI.classList.contains('active'))
    {
    myMenu.querySelector('li.active').classList.remove('active');
    }
  LI.classList.add('active');
  }
```

```css
ul#menu {
  list-style: none;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .3em .5em;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul#menu li::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background-color: #3399FF;
}
ul#menu li.active::before,
ul#menu li:hover::before {
  left:0%;
}
ul#menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Main Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have fully understood what you want, but here a snippet:

```js
const menu_links = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-link"))

function handleClick(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  menu_links.forEach(link => link.classList.remove("link-active"))
  evt.target.classList.add("link-active")
}

menu_links.forEach(link => link.addEventListener("click", handleClick))
```

```css
.underline {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #3399FF;
}

ul li a:hover > .underline {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}

.link-active {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #3399FF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      Main Page<div class="link-mark underline link-active"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      Blog<div class="link-mark underline"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      Contact<div class="link-mark underline"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      More<div class="link-mark underline"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

- Instead of changing the `left`, I think it's better to change the `width` (it will avoid overflow issues).
- Why keeping both `menu_links` and `active`? Only one is enough